# Spring is not finding bean in an integration test using mock mvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I am trying to test a spring boot controller using mockmvc, but it seems like spring boot is not finding the service: TranslatorService

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class TranslatorController {

    private final TranslatorService translatorService;

    public TranslatorController(TranslatorService translatorService) {
        this.translatorService = translatorService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/translator")
    private ResponseEntity<TranslatorOutput> translateText(@RequestBody TranslatorInput translatorInput) {
        TranslatorOutput translatorOutput = translatorService.translateText(translatorInput);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(translatorOutput);
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
@WebMvcTest(TranslatorController.class)
class TranslatorControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testTranslateTextEndpoint() throws Exception {
       
        TranslatorInput input = new TranslatorInput("Hello", "en", "es");

       
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/translator")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(input)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.sourceLanguage").exists()) 
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.targetLanguage").exists()) 
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.translatedText").exists()); 
    }
}
```

And I am getting the next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@67fc2aad testClass = com.translator.demo.controller.TranslatorControllerTest, locations = [], classes = [com.translator.demo.DemoApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@56f521c6 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4bff7da0, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@47c81abf, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@35a3d49f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@f848d63b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@f0767283, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@62833051, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@d5f9521c], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
```

and this is my service:

```
@Service
public class TranslatorService {
    private final AmazonTranslate amazonTranslate;
    public TranslatorService(AmazonTranslate amazonTranslate) {
        this.amazonTranslate = amazonTranslate;
    }

    public TranslatorOutput translateText(TranslatorInput translatorInput) {
        TranslateTextRequest request = new TranslateTextRequest()
                .withText(translatorInput.text())
                .withSourceLanguageCode(translatorInput.source())
                .withTargetLanguageCode(translatorInput.target());
        TranslateTextResult result = amazonTranslate.translateText(request);
        TranslatorOutput translatorOutput = new TranslatorOutput(translatorInput.source(),
                translatorInput.target(), result.getTranslatedText(), new Date());
        return translatorOutput;
    }
}
```

This is the caused by:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'translatorController' defined in file [C:\Training\sdkAws\demo1\awsTranslator\target\classes\com\translator\demo\controller\TranslatorController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.translator.demo.service.TranslatorService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187) ~[spring-test-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119) ~[spring-test-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.translator.demo.service.TranslatorService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1824) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1383) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas? thanks!!

Comment: can u add caused by log from the error?

Comment: sure, I added the cause by

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [javadoc for @WebMvcTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html)?

> Annotation that can be used for a Spring MVC test that focuses **only** on Spring MVC components.
>
> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).

TranslatorService is not a part of the MVC components, it is not available in the context, thus the controller cannot be constructed.

> Typically @WebMvcTest is used in combination with @MockBean or @Import to create any collaborators required by your @Controller beans.

If you add a @MockBean TranslatorService in your test class, all required beans will be in the context, thus enabling the controller to be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your test class is correctly configured to load the Spring context. The @WebMvcTest annotation, which you are using, is meant for testing web controllers and might not load all beans by default. Make sure that your test configuration includes the package where TranslatorService is located.

You can customize the component scanning in your test configuration using @ComponentScan:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.translator.demo") // Add the package where TranslatorService is located
class TranslatorControllerTest {
    // ...
}
```